# Python scripting pkl file

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have implemented a model using Sagemaker and post training the model file is saved as `.tar.gz in S3 bucket. I want to read a .pkl file for prediction.

Is there a way to convert `tar` file to `pkl` file format in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first extract the tar.gz file

You can do so by using the following command in Linux
`tar -xvzf community_images.tar.gz`

for more detail you can follow this post [unzip/extract a tar.gz file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file)

For windows you can use [WinZip](https://www.winzip.com/win/en/tar-gz-file.html)

After it it will give you a bunch of file or a single file which can then be read using suitable code.

Maybe this might be useful... [Load test and optimize an Amazon SageMaker endpoint using automatic scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/load-test-and-optimize-an-amazon-sagemaker-endpoint-using-automatic-scaling/)